# Entity DataSource not working with Entity Framework 6 Upgrade

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entitydatasource

I recently upgraded our Webforms application from EF 4.4 to EF6 and I got so many compile time build errors with the Entity Datasource controls. Generally I am getting these error in all occurrences when trying to access the context object :

```
e.Context
```

I have followed the same walkthrough as given in : http://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Updating%20Applications%20to%20use%20EF6

The error information which is showing up is:

> 1) Module System.Data.Entity. version="4.0.0.0" should be referenced
>
> 2) Cannot case expression of type System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext to
>   type ObjectContext (After explicitly type casting to System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext)

Can anybody help to fix this?

Comment: Have you Changed  in the Designer file of Edmx Model ?
Check the designer file of Entity framework and change from this
internal class YourDataContext : ObjectContext
to 
internal class YourDataContext : Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext

Comment: Yes we have tried this, but no luck.

Comment: The EntityDataSourceControl that is currently available does not support EF6. We are working on making an EF6 enabled version available. Stay tuned.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just went through this exercise when upgrading to EF 6 from EF 5 and I had the same errors.

Here is what I had to do.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.EntityDataSource
```

It would register a new EntityDataSource Control in the web.config under pages:

```
<pages>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="ef" assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.EntityDataSource" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.EntityDataSource" />
  </controls>
</pages>
```

Next step is to replace existing `<asp:EntityDataSource />` controls to `<ef:EntityDataSource />` in your aspx pages.

Final step is to go in your code behind and update references for EntityDataSourceContextCreatingEventArgs or any other type of EFContext tags.

From

```
protected void OnContextCreating(object sender, EntityDataSourceContextCreatingEventArgs e){... }
```

To

```
protected void OnContextCreating(object sender, Microsoft.AspNet.EntityDataSource.EntityDataSourceContextCreatingEventArgs e){... }
```

It all worked and I didn't have to reference System.Data.Entity in the assembly.

Comment: In addition, you should remove properties DefaultContainerName and ConnectionString, and just set ContextTypeName on the EntityDataSource.

Answer (score 2):

The Entity DataSource control for EF6 is available <del>in preview since 2014-01-30 (details in [this Microsoft announcement](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/01/30/announcing-preview-of-dynamic-data-provider-and-entitydatasource-control-for-entity-framework-6.aspx)). It is available</del> as a nuget package : http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.EntityDataSource/

<del>If you try to download it from the nuget package manager, be sure to select the "include prerelease" item in the top combo Box.</del>

Answer (score 0):

As per the suggestions given by the IDE, we can go to the NuGet Package Console and run the following command to install the new Entity Framework data source:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.EntityDataSource
```

Also, add the following package (as referred in [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/announcing-the-release-of-dynamic-data-provider-and-entitydatasource-control-for-entity-framework-6/) article):

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.DynamicData.EFProvider
```