# Unable to load the specified metadata resource error in Entity Framework 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I use ASP.NET Webforms and Entity Framework 4 and this is my `.edmx` file screenshot because I don't know what code to post here:

[image]

And this is my connection string in my web.config file:

```
<add name="tebimir_db_tebimEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataAccessLayer.tebimir_db_tebim.csdl|res://*/DataAccessLayer.tebimir_db_tebim.ssdl|res://*/DataAccessLayer.tebimir_db_tebim.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=tebim.ir,9993;initial catalog=tebimir_db_tebim;persist security info=True;user id=tebimir_dbadmin;password=qwerty*2607548;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

My `.edmx` file in inside a folder named `DataAccessLayer`. When I use Entity Framework, it works fine and there is no problem but ONLY when I create an `entityDataSource` control and want to assign my `.edmx` to it, I get an error that the metadata could not be found, otherwise it works correctly.

I mean I can access data using Entity Framework. I checked all the questions related in stack-overflow but could not find an answer. Please help.

[image]

These are additional information in case it can help you:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I am reading it.. :-)

Comment: Are you sure that you have 'Build' your project before using the entity datasource control?

Comment: Yes. lots of times!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739959/entity-framework-unable-to-load-the-specified-metadata-resource

Comment: i have read them all, my error is only when I want to work with EntityDataSource. Thanks :)

Comment: update entity framework 6 version then you try

Comment: What is your VS version? Did you try to update your EF to 6 and also run it with VS2015?

Comment: my vs is 2013, i cant use EF 6 because EntityDataSource control is not compatible with EF6.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25836705/entitydatasource-and-entity-framework-6

Comment: Hi, are you sure the EntityDataSource is using the right connectionstring? Maybe it's using a connectionstring from another project, thus another config file.

Comment: How can i be assure?

Comment: Are you seeing anything in DefaultContainerName drop down or it is empty?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you will not face this issue on VS 2012. This is Visual Studio 2013 specific issue and I was able to reproduce it. Here is the solution:

1. Double click on your edmx file in solution explorer to open it in edmx designer. Right click on empty surface. Click "Model Browser" from context menu.
2. In Model Browser window select the conceptual model node. It will be parallel to and just below diagrams node. By default name of this node is database name concatenated with string "Model". Like if my database name is Employee then this node is seen as EmployeeModel. Right click on conceptual model node. Click on Properties from the context menu.
3. Change the value of "Meta Artifact Processing" property from "Embed in Output Assembly" to "Copy to Output Directory"

[image]

Now you can point your `entityDataSource` control to this edmx through Configure Data Source wizard without error. See the note in the ".edmx file properties" section of below link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc982042%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I did, That way I get the same error when im not using entityDataSource control to access my data. EntityDataSource is ok now but I cant access my data directly.

Comment: I had done this before. I agree that this answer is correct about EntityDataSource but not an answer about the problem. Thanks any way

Comment: What do you mean by this `That way I get the same error when im not using entityDataSource control to access my data`? What is that error? Are you saying that after making all the changes I've suggested when you actually bind the edmx to control, the entityDataSource doesn't get the records present in database?

Comment: No! when I bind the edmx to control, say gridview, fields are not retrieved. column names are unknown, when i refresh gridview schema it gives error. i dont know. whatever i just created another project and recreated everything from start. I really hate microsoft products.

Comment: I will look into it if I also face the same issue with grid view control. Unfortunately the machine on which I was running your code on VS 2013 has been shut down due to a maintenance work over the weekend :(

Comment: Anyway i give you the bounty. thanks for your efforts.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you have misconfigured the property *MetadataArtifactProcessing*.

Try setting `MetadataArtifactProcessing = EntityDeploy`

Comment: upvote to encourage you to keep answering questions :)

Comment: Well, comments are comments, not answers. It's better to upvote real answers.