# Entity Framework 6: Use EntityDataSource for Binding?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a database-first EDMX Datamodel.
I'm using the new Microsoft.AspNet.EntityDataSource control for EF6 to bind to DevExpress controls & utilize the rich design-time features. (such as automatic column generation in the aspxgridview, based on the datasource schema)

Using the EF6 DataSource
[image]

Then in the GridView Designer, FieldNames aren't populated from the Schema.
[image]

In his answer, Rowan Miller stated:

> We no longer recommend using the Entity Data Source for new projects

[EntityDataSource and Entity Framework 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25836705/entitydatasource-and-entity-framework-6)

... so is there a better Datasource type to use? 
What's the proper way to do this type of binding with EF6?

Comment: The answer mentions what their recommendation is "You need to perform configuration directly in the markup."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EntityDataSource and Entity Framework 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25836705/entitydatasource-and-entity-framework-6)

Answer (score 0):

I learned from [Entity DataSource not working with Entity Framework 6 Upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25066396) how to get the new EntityDataSource that works with EntityFramework 6 and by following the instructions there you can drop the old EntityDataSource on to the designer from the toolbox and then make the changes according to Sergey's answer and LMK's comment.

Then you can continue working with that EntityDataSource from the designer or markup.