# How do I make use of the tagPrefix ef in an ASP.NET WebForms app using EF6?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, webforms

I'm trying to use an EntityDataSource on an ASP.NET WebForms app I'm writing using VS 2015. I found this post [Entity DataSource not working with Entity Framework 6 Upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792144/entity-datasource-not-working-with-entity-framework-6-upgrade), which is helpful but I've still got an issue. In this case I'm not trying to update an app, I'm creating a new one. I've already installed the EntityDataSource package from NuGet, exactly as described in the linked post. I see that the EntityDataSource has been added to the  section of my Web.Config. However, when I go inito the HTML view and start typing

```
<ef:
```

VS 2015 doesn't understand what I've typed. There's no Intellisense. So I presume that VS 2015 isn't aware of it as I thought it would be. What more do I have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know why this would make a difference, but today all of a sudden, it works. Besides being a different day (that can't be why), the only thing I can think of is that I got out of VS 2015 yesterday and got back into it today. Why that would make a difference, I don't know. But it looks like it did.