# "Could not find file or assembly' -- get more information?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2017

I'm dealing with that error message again. In this particular case, it is:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.EntityDataSource' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to get more information. For example, apparently it couldn't find a file, could I get the path where it looked?

Comment: have a look at this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25066396/185655

Comment: bingo, solved the immediate problem, thanks. I'm still interested in the general question of getting more info out of that error message.

Comment: [Fusion log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer) can help in most cases.