# EntityDataSource & Entity Framework 6 | OnContextCreating issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6, datasource

I tried to add EntityDataSource from NuGet for entity framework 6.0.
Please take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25836705/entitydatasource-and-entity-framework-6).
And also take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25066396/268588).
The problem is i can not find this piece of code in my code behind for replace :

```
protected void OnContextCreating(object sender, EntityDataSourceContextCreatingEventArgs e){... }
```

Where is it?
Should i add it manually to code behind?
What exactly should be those codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OnContextCreating() is the event that is only called when the EntityDataSource creates the ObjectContext that is used to work with entity data objects.

Check the link below for details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.entitydatasource.contextcreating?view=netframework-4.8